# How can I make a WebMethod parameter required

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

We use the "start from Java" approach to creating JAX-WS 2.0 web services using the Metro 1.5 stack.  When we point a standard tool like SoapUI at one of our web services it indicates that parameters to WebMethods are optional.  The generated xsd shows minOccurs=0.

I need a way to make WebMethod parameters required (maybe minOccurs=1 in the xsd) in the "start from Java" approach.  I would think there is a Java annotation for this, but I haven't been able to find one.  The XmlElement annotation has required attribute, but XmlElement cannot be applied to WebMethod parameters.

Is there a way to make my WebMethod parameters required, short of manually editing the xsd and setting minOccurs to 1?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've verified that Metro 2.0 does allow you to set `@XmlElement(required=true)` on a parameter.  The generated xsd does not have `minOccurs=0`.  It leaves `minOccurs` out of the generated xsd so it assumes the default value of 1.

You also have to upgrade your JDK by putting the JAX-WS 2.2 `webservices-api.jar` in the `endorsed/` directory.

I posted the same question [on the Java forums](http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/How-can-I-make-a-WebMethod-parameter-required-td1067651.html).

Thanks to jitu for both the answer and pointing out that minOccurs defaults to 1 so leaving it out of the .xsd has the desired effect.

When @XmlElement(required=true) is set on the parameter SoapUI no longer indicates that the parameter as optional.

Answer (score 6):

> The generated xsd shows minOccurs=0.

This is per specification: any non-primitives are optional, only primitives are required.

> I need a way to make WebMethod parameters required (maybe minOccurs=1 in the xsd) in the "start from Java" approach.

This is not possible, unless you use primitives as previously mentioned.

And actually, this is one of the reasons why Java-first sucks (yeah, developers like it but [it just does not work](http://sberyozkin.blogspot.com/2007/11/jax-ws-30-wish-list.html)): its fragile, the contract may change(!), its doesn't give you all the control you need, it doesn't [fit well with WS-Security](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=64969), etc. So, indeed, [contract-first](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/why-contract-first.html) is not pleasant, but at least, it works.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the links.  I wish those bloated web services books out there (some of which I've read - I mean waded through) would have just said this as clearly as you have.

Comment: @Dean You're welcome. And thanks for the feedback on JAX-WS 2.2 (even if this was not really in the scope of the initial question).

Comment: I would say that WSDL-first equally does not work. The blog you link to talks about using complex Request and Return objects for wrapping, but this presents a number of problems, such as hiding required things in the underlying fields, abuse of reuse, etc...then again, I would hold up an example of something good as using Spring and proxies to make something like a WebService appear as a simple implementation of an interface locally. Gumming up your local interface in this way is part of what keeps you from forgetting that it's a service that *happens* to be exposed via JAX-WS.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another discussion of this same question.  According to the response Metro 2.0  supports putting @XmlElement on a method parameter which should solve my problem.

http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=385565&#385565

Metro 2.0 was released on Dec. 10, 2009 so it is no longer in EA.  I'll give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: It seems to work, but the provided link is 404, any chance to get an updated source?