# webservices IRAD 7

Tags: java, web-services

I am working on webservice botttom up approch on IRAD 7 with jaxws 2.1.and jaxb

I want to make webmethod parameters mandatory,I tried using @Xmlelement(required=true)
but it is not updating my XSd.

Can you suggest a suitable approch to make my webmethod paramets mandatory

Thanks in Advance.
rama.

Answer (score 0):

The JAX-WS runtime for Websphere is Axis2. You can find an example in [Java Web services: JAXB and JAX-WS in Axis2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jws8/index.html) using required parameters.

For Metro runtime, check this question in [How can I make a WebMethod parameter required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210346/how-can-i-make-a-webmethod-parameter-required)